# React-native. - dynamic access to the object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mapreduce, lodash, reduce

When I send a request, which key I will get from the data will come from the config file.
for example :

```
{
"da": [
    {
        "bc": {
            "name": [
                { "a": "https://via.placeholder.com" },
                { "a": "https://via.placeholder.com" },
                { "a": "https://via.placeholder.com" },
                { "a": "https://via.placeholder.com" },
                { "a": "https://via.placeholder.com" }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

the "a" I need

I added config.json as apiType = "a".
When data returns, I have to go directly to the "a" . Which api changes, it will be enough for me to make changes only from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily dynamically access JS object values with the `object[key]` syntax.

```
const dynamicKey = "a";

const listOfUrls = da[0].bc.name.map(n => n[dynamicKey]);
```

Comment: It will only go with the key without knowing the incoming data sequence. When the api url changes, it should be integrated with the key I added to the config.json file.

Comment: Please post the exact example of what your api response will look like, and what it might change to. Then show what your config to access it will be, and how you are trying to change it.

Comment: The API response is changeable, all I know is the "name" key in config.json.

Comment: I'd like to help but I need MUCH much more information about your problem. Please take a some time to post what your api responses will look like, what your config looks like, what they might change to, and the code you've used to try to solve this problem.

Comment: By changing the config.json file, it was never
an application that is unknown and can work with any API that gives url in a list
should be.